# Pushing error in github over proxy enabled network?

Tags: git, ssh, proxy

I am inside a university network which uses proxy to access net. I am unable to access git hub through ssh and also https. I have setup ssh_config also netrc but getting error. Please help me out?

`git push -u origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

my ssh config file

```
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no


Host github.com
ProxyCommand /usr/bin/corkscrew 202.141.80.19 3128 %h %p ~/.ssh/myauth
User git
Port 443
Hostname ssh.github.com
TCPKeepAlive yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

my netrc contain

```
`machine github.com
`username   user@gmail.com`
`password   password`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check your repository configuration: `git remote -v` should give you an url of the form:

`git@github.com:yournick/yourproject.git`

- Check that your private SSH key is listed on your [github account](https://github.com/settings/ssh). If it is, you should be able to do `ssh git@github.com` and see something like:

`Hi yournick! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

See also:

- [Relevant help for this error](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)
- [Using SSH over the HTTPS port (should you need it)](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port)